# Confusion in line about Body Content

Tags: java, jsp

I'm really confused in the following line about the `BodyContent` class, which I've taken from the Javadoc:

> Note that the content of `BodyContent`
>   is the result of evaluation, so it
>   will not contain actions and the like,
>   but the result of their invocation.

I really don't get it, what do they mean in above line.

Comment: I think you have to provide some more informations

Comment: Sorry, it was actually 'Body Content', instead of 'Body Tag'. I've modified it.

Answer (score 0):

If there is anything which needs to be evaluated / rendered in the body (i.e. code executed), then it will have been executed and the results included in the content. To put it another way, the content will contain no un-executed actions.

Answer (score 0):

It says that BodyContent  contains generated result(HTML + JavaScript) of the executed action

if you had

```
 < ... outputText   ...  value=#{someValue}>
```

in BodyContent  you will have something like this just not so simple

```
 <p>someValue<p>
```